# Fahrenheit to Celsius table C

Tags: c

I am working on a code that displays a conversion table from Fahrenheit to Celsius.How can I change it so that it will start from negative value and go towards positive something like this

```
Fahrenhite  Celcius  
-10   -23.3333 
-20   -28.8889 
 .. 
 .. 
 .. 
 ..
 100   37.7778
```

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
      float fahrenheit, celsius;
      int lower, upper, step;

      lower = 10;
      upper = 100;
      step = 10;
      printf("F       C\n\n");
      fahrenheit = lower;
      while(fahrenheit <= upper)
             {
            celsius = (5.0 / 9.0) * (fahrenheit - 32.0);
            printf("%3.0f %6.1f\n", fahrenheit, celsius);
            fahrenheit = fahrenheit + step;
             }

                  return 0;
}
```

Comment: One word: Seriously?

Comment: How about... changing the lower limit to a negative value?

Comment: It's not "your" code, is it? Your question shows that you have not a slightest idea how this code works. Stackoverflow is not a "do my homework for me" site.

Comment: 1. Open the code with your favorite text editor or IDE. 2. Modify the code. 3. Compile and run.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must learn how to work this code it is so simply an clear.
Your code works for lower=10 and upper=100 you can change these values what are you want you can reach table. If you want 4 digits after the conviction

```
 printf("%3.0f %6.4f\n", fahrenheit, celsius);
```

you must chage %6.1f like above

Answer (score 0):

-10 is greater than -100. So,
You can put `lower = -100`.
Then your answer will come as expected.

```
F       C

-100  -73.3
-90  -67.8
-80  -62.2
-70  -56.7
-60  -51.1
-50  -45.6
-40  -40.0
-30  -34.4
-20  -28.9
-10  -23.3
  0  -17.8
 10  -12.2
 20   -6.7
 30   -1.1
 40    4.4
 50   10.0
 60   15.6
 70   21.1
 80   26.7
 90   32.2
100   37.8
```